# How to produce a URL for editing one of my existing Google Calendar events?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am working on a Chrome extension for Google Calendar and I have access to all the JavaScript global variables defined by Google. The task is to send a user from some other page to their "edit event details" page in Google Calendar. Is there a URL for that? What tricks are known to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Event object's `htmlLink` field has what you want.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#htmlLink